# Web: How to center right div for all screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix my header div which has two components. An Image and the title of the page as shown in the figure:

The image shown below is on MDPI screen.

[image]

Here is my Code

```css
#headerdiv {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 1% 0;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.headerdiv>#leftheaderdiv {
  min-height: 750px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headerdiv">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="leftheaderdiv">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports" id="mainlogo" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="leftheaderdiv">
    <p id="headerdivp">TXYZ RD MEDIA</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this on a mobile screen, which is fine as per the bootstrap arrangement:

[image]

**The problem I am facing is on HDPI screen where the header looks like this. The text goes on the top.**:

[image]

How Can I make sure that the right div also occupies 100% height / fills the right part and the text is always in the middle no matter what screen size?

Thank you!

Comment: use `flexbox` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

You can use `flex` to align the text in vertically center. Add the following CSS in your paragraph parent element like below.

```
.headerdiv > #leftheaderdiv{
  min-height: 750px; 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

**Solution 2:**

If you don't want to use flex you can use the old method like make your parent as `table` and child element as `table-cell`.

```
 #headerdivp{
    font-size: 4em; 
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 60px; 
    padding: 1% 0; 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: auto auto;
  }

 .headerdiv > #leftheaderdiv{
    min-height: 750px; 
    display:table;    
    text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **flex**..

For vertical align center use `align-items:center`.

And for mobile stacked view use `flex-direction:column` using media query.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#headerdivp {
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.headerdiv>#leftheaderdiv {
  text-align: center;
}

.headerdiv {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .headerdiv {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="headerdiv row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="leftheaderdiv">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports" id="mainlogo" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="leftheaderdiv">
      <p id="headerdivp">TXYZ RD MEDIA</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Reference Link**

- [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)
- [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)
- [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `row` class. Also add class `align-items-center`. Also also have id `leftheaderdiv` twice. Make it unique.

```
<div class = "row headerdiv align-items-center">               
            <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id = "leftheaderdiv">
                <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/xesdcf/xdclogo3d2.svg" id = "mainlogo"/>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id = "leftheaderdiv">
                <p id = "headerdivp">TXYZ RD MEDIA</p>              
            </div>
</div>
```